# Get parent data element from dragged element - Drag en drop function

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, element, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to retrieve a parent data attribute `data-date` of the dragged object in JavaScript.
So i want to receive the data-date attribute `<td>` from where the `div` "drag me" was dragged from.

**HTML example:**

```
<td data-date="2/3/2020">
<div>drag me</div>
</td>

<td data-date="3/3/2020">
<-- DIV "Drag Me" will be dragged to this location --!>
</td>
```

I am able to retrieve the dropped data-date attribute, but cant figure out how to retrieve the dragged from data-date attribute.

**JS From and TO current code**

```
       dropped = ui.draggable,
       newDate = $(this).data('date'),
       console.log('Date From :' + dropped.data('date')); // needs to be found
       console.log('Date To:' + newDate); // Works correctly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around to pass information from the **draggable** function to **droppable** function

In the example below i first get the data-date value from the parent  element in the draggable function.
After retrieving this data we pass the value from draggable to the droppable function.

We name de variable **oldDate** so we can access it in the droppable function by calling "ui.draggable.data('oldDate')". Ill provide an example code for you guys below.

**Draggable function:**

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair",
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var oldDate = $(this).parent().data('date'); // get value from parent data-date attribute
        $(this).data('oldDate', oldDate); // pass variable to droppable function
    }
});
```

**Droppable function:**

```
 $("td[data-date]").droppable({
    accept: ".drag", 
    activeClass: "over",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var displayOldDate = ui.draggable.data('oldDate'); // access the variable saved in draggable function 
        console.log('Dragged from: ' + displayOldDate);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways how to manage it

1. I better prefer to save an initial parent element into some variable when start dragging.
2. Another option could be have all the needed data on the dragged element itself